# I am not able to install the mavens mate properly.It is showing the error after package installation.The error is shown below.can somebody help me?

Tags: mavensmate

Error trying to parse settings: Expected value in Packages/User/mavensmate.sublime-settings:21:2

Comment: Not an answer but a comment -- i just had to revert back to eclipse ide after mavensmate introduced their new mm.app build and started causing many users real headaches. They also started rolling back builds. I lost a few projects along the way. Suggest you wait until there is a stable build - it literally changes every few days it seems at the moment.